# How to download a blob image from java server to iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have created a program which allows me to upload images to Java Server thru Multipart.
How can I receive an image from server and download it to iPhone app? Is there any way apart from NSURL i can download the image?

Base64 Encoding & Decoding  seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're downloading is base64 encoded, you can just download it using NSURLConnection. Once you have the data downloaded, base64 decode the data and put it into an NSData that can then be loaded into a UIImage. A solution for doing that can be found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847875/how-to-get-uiimage-from-a-base64string-format-raw-image-data-on-iphone).

No matter what, though, you're going to need NSURL. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) provided a Core Foundation networking abstraction that is an alternative to NSURLConnection, however, it's bloated and it is no longer being maintained by the original author (though there are probably some forks that are being maintained).