# Convert base64string to UIImage

Tags: objective-c

I have image base64 string,so please tell me how to convert base64string to
UIImage. I am using following code but its not working.

```
NSString *base64String=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[objDIC objectForKey:@"signDriver"]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];    
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get UIImage from a 'Base64String' format raw image data, on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847875/how-to-get-uiimage-from-a-base64string-format-raw-image-data-on-iphone)

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk), I think is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

Get the code from the Matt Gallagher [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) site. Go to the section: "Handling Base64 on the iPhone", "Decoding Base64".

Turn in a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple requesting base64 support be added, I have, the more the better chance Apple will add it to the SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] expects to be given a file: URL that points to a file on disk with the given image in a format that UIImage (actually, Core Graphics) knows how to open.

You already have the image data stored in base64String, so you should be able to just grab the data from the string using dataUsingEncoding.

Comment: Now i am using following code and also getting imagedata but image is null

Comment: NSString *base64String=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[objDIC objectForKey:@"signDriver"]];
            NSData *imageData = [base64String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
            UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            NSLog(@"imageData--%@",imageData);

Comment: `NSUTF32StringEncoding` is not base64 encoding, there is no NSStringEncoding for base64.